# Error when creating Shopify Collect: {'base': ["can't be blank"]}

Tags: python, shopify-api

I'm using the Python [ShopifyAPI](https://pypi.org/project/ShopifyAPI/) codebase
and I'm attempting to create a Collect in Shopify which associates a Product and a CustomCollection. I am receiving an error I don't receive when creating any other data type (Metafields, Images) etc.

My Code:

```
product_id="5065546170508"
collection_id="186757611660"

z=shopify.Collect()
z.product_id = product_id
z.collection_id = collection_id
z.save()
```

Error in the terminal:

```
{'base': collect(None), 'errors': {'base': ["can't be blank"]}}
```

The collect is created however I receive a "False" when running .save()

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple mistake, but I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone down the road. My script was creating new CustomCollections each time it ran, and I wasn't updating the CustomCollection IDs so the collect couldn't be created. I updated the script to grab the new CustomCollection ID and that solved my problem.